# Reading file using Common Lisp

Tags: file-io, lisp, common-lisp

I need to read a text file using Common Lisp. File must be read to list of lists. Each list in the list must consist of a line from file. How to do this? I have done only this:

```
(let ((in (open "D:/Others/rgr.txt")))
  (format t "~a~%" (read-line in))
  (close in))
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
(with-open-file (in file)
  (loop for line = (read-line in nil nil)
        while line
        collect (coerce line 'list)))
```